# Count number of lines in textView

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application where i need to charge the user based on the number of pages. Can anyone tell me how can i derive number of pages if the data is entered as multiline in textView.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSString's `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method to calculate the space a given amount of text would occupy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code it works fine

```
 -(float)getHeightByWidth:(NSString*)myString:(UIFont*)mySize:(int)myWidth

 {

CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(myWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize requiredSize = [myString sizeWithFont:mySize constrainedToSize:boundingSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  
return requiredSize.height;
}
```